# Android navigate up the right graph when using NavController

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I'm currently using Android Navigation Architecture in my project. It has a feature that can launch any fragment with a shortcut.
Suppose my navigation graph looks like this: A->B->C->D.
When I'm at fragment A , I directly navigate to fragment D with NavController.navigate(R.id.fragment_d). But when I'm press back button, it returns to fragment A. Is there any way to let the destination navigate back to its parent in navigation graph? (I mean, in this case, D back to C, B then back to A).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your navigation function.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should always avoid creating a synthetic back stack when within your own app (and only do this when launching your app from a deep link outside your app, i.e., via an [app shortcut](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts)).

However, you can approach this in one of two ways:

1. If you're okay with resetting the state on A, you can use [NavDeepLinkBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavDeepLinkBuilder) to construct a set of Intents suitable for restarting your task on the chosen destination:

   ```
   navController.createDeepLink()
     .setDestination(R.id.destination_d)
     .createTaskStackBuilder()
     .startActivites()
   ```
2. Just call `navigate()` multiple times.

   ```
   navController.navigate(R.id.destination_b)
   navController.navigate(R.id.destination_c)
   navController.navigate(R.id.destination_d)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it can not solves my problem. The first option din't works, the second option is impossible, because I just want to know the last destination and don't know about what destination leading to it.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific when you say "didn't work". If you don't know about what destinations you want on the back stack, how do you expect to know what to add? Someone has to know :-)

Comment: The requirement is that you can quickly navigate to any fragment with a shortcuts. The natural way if you want to navigate to that fragment is visualized in navigation graph. (Suppose every fragment wants to use shortcuts to navigated to have only one start point in navigation graph). So, what I want on the back stack is the fragments that can lead to that destination in a natural way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use `navControler.navigateUp()` on the destination if you have correctly introduced the parent fragment for your fragments. Also, consider the difference between the device back button and up back-arrow to go up to the parent